# How to set up redirect uri for Facebook oauth authorization using dotnet core on docker when running behind IIS reverse proxy

Tags: docker, iis, oauth, .net-core, reverse-proxy

We are building a web application with dotnet core running inside docker containers. We have put the app behind IIS on WS2016 which is used as reverse proxy. The requests incoming to our URL (www.myurl.com) are forwarded to the related docker container using the container name as the hostname with the help of url rewrite module(in our case, let's call it "web"). This setup works up to here.

However, a few days ago we needed to add Facebook oauth authorization support to register to the system and a problem appeared. We setup our authorization as the following:

```
...
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(o =>
{
    o.CallbackPath = new PathString("/account/facebookreturn");
    o.AppId = appSettings.FacebookLogin.AppId;
    o.AppSecret = appSettings.FacebookLogin.AppSecret;
})
...
```

Our facebook authentication challenge then redirects user to facebook oauth page with the following redirect uri:
https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth......redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fweb%2Faccount%2Ffacebookreturn&state=....

As you see the `redirect_uri` has the container name / hostname of the docker container whereas it should actually be "www.myurl.com".

We tried several solutions such as using `x-forwarded` headers. Using `UseIISIntegration()` and `UseUrls` did not seem to work either. What are we missing here? I am not much experienced with IIS and web headers, so it could be fairly obvious, and I appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I thought I have replied to this comment -.- Nope, unfortunately. We had switched to Traefik from IIS at the time, not just because of this, but because of many similar problems. IIS and docker does not play well.